# Change button label and add listener

Tags: android, button, dialog

I'm using a button to add new button on runtime and also need to change the button label but it is showing only the predefined.can some tell me how to change new added button label. My code to add new button:

```
addnew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    addnew.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v == addnew)
    {

        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
        count++;
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

To store the button created I'm using SharedPreferences in onCreate:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    count=prefs.getInt("count", 0);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("New Button");
        myButton.setId(count);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);
    }
```

Also can we apply onClickListener on added button like my other buttons have. Code :

```
bdialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btndialog);
    property.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == bdialog)
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_layout);
        Button report = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Report);
        report.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on Report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reverting Changes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
        });
        // Showing Alert Dialog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

I'm using predefined xml layout for my dialog box

Comment: addnew.setText("whatever text") will help you change the text of the addNew button

Comment: But I need to change Button text on runtime. this will provide a button with predefined text

Comment: which portion of the code do u wish to change the button text ?? And do you want to change the text of the new button ?? or the old button ?

Comment: I want to change the text of new button added not the old button which is used to add new button

Comment: The code that you hve written works fine for adding a new button and btn.setText() does set the text of the button to "" , instead of "" place the text that you want

Comment: Button myButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
myButton.setText("New Button");

Comment: And yes it is possible to give clicks to dynamic buttons, just give them unique ids at runtime and identify which button has been clicked

Comment: how to give unique ids at run time

Comment: myButton.setId(count)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, when you add a button to a layout, the "myButton" variable is useless, what you can do is create a new id for your button:

```
myButton.setId(id); //id is any positive number
```

and when you want to change the button at any way (for example it's text) do this:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(id);
myButton.setText("My Text");
```

just make sure each dynamically created button has different id

If you want it to have a listener, you can do it either before adding the button to the layout, or when you are changing the button (with findViewById)

If there are many dynamic changes in your activity, I suggest to make everything dynamically, including the layouts, it's just easier for you in my opinion

Comment: For id i'm using count which is declare globally count=0